# High quality question and answers?

Tags: support, questions, answers

We have so many high quality questions and answers which may become outdated as the technology changes after some years or so, then they might be of no use further. How they can be filtered or what else can be done to them ?

Comment: Usually the answers regarding use of certain technology are updated over time. Some questions are purely programming questions not entirely based on technology, in which concepts don't change.

Comment: I'm sure there are many posts about this, so I'll be brief: One person's _outdated_ is another person's _stable_, _legacy_ or _my-boss's-favorite_.  An old question/answer can still be a good, useful answer.  (And if it's bad, it doesn't matter how old it is.)